# using mapply on a function with multiple arguments not giving expected result

Tags: r, sapply

I would like to use sapply or mapply to perform the function below over numbers from 3:5 and 9:10. In short, I would like to do the following

```
3^2 + 9 = 18
4^2 + 9 = 25
5^2 + 9 = 34

3^2 + 10 = 19
4^2 + 10 = 26
5^2 + 10 = 35
```

However, I would like to specify both values, ie 3:5 and 9:10 as arguments. I'm able to use sapply when the function expects only a single argument and also able to use mapply when the function expects two arguments, of which the second one is not a list of elements. How can I perform the same with two arguments,both of which are lists?

```
 > mapply(myfunc,3:5,9)
[1] 18 25 34
> mapply(myfunc,3:5,9:10)
[1] 18 26 34
Warning message:
In mapply(myfunc, 3:5, 9:10) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you might use the function `outer`:

```
> outer(3:5, 9:10, function(x, y) { x^2 + y })
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   18   19
[2,]   25   26
[3,]   34   35
```

But be aware that the applied function must be vectorized.